# Monitor Git push in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to monitor or view the git push from Visual Studio Code? i.e. "Pushing file 123/345" or "Pushing [filename]" or any version of that? or any kind of view as if you were FTPing and watching the files as they get uploaded. I have searched for the past couple of hours on google and I could find nothing to that effect.

Thanks.

Comment: `git` doesn't push files, it pushes references (branches and tags) and commits. Commits contain files but `git` doesn't report pushed files in commits separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `git push` from an integrated terminal inside of VS Code and then you will see some information as the files are pushed.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

You can also monitor the output of the git tools available within VS Code by opening the output window and choosing Git. On Linux, the command to open this output window is [Ctrl + k, Ctrl + h].